# Selecting a .command file's parent directory

Tags: bash, terminal, directory, parent

I am creating a bash program (.command) on my Mac, and I need to be able to select the file's parent directory (directory that it is inside) no matter where it is. For example, if the file is under ~/Desktop/file.command, I want to be able to select the Desktop folder.

Note: by saying select, I mean that I want to be able to use a command on it (cp, mv, cd, ls, etc.)

Comment: In that case, use **.** (single period), for example: cp ./somefile.txt ~/backup

Comment: The first *positional parameter* to a script is always the script name (with full path) So within the script, `"$0"` is the script name with full path. You can always get the current script directory with `dirname "$0"`. You can get the parent for the current with say `current="$(dirname "$0")"`, then `parent="${current%/*}"`

Comment: Technically, `$0` is not a positional parameter; it's a special parameter.

Comment: Agreed, there was some mental frailty as I searched for the right term.